# NextJS API request (with prisma) on client site page

Tags: javascript, next.js

Im looking for a solution to fetch my database data on a NextJS page which is marked with "use client" as an client page.
"use client" is needed for the theme I'm using.
Currently I have an page which is requesting the data from the database and redirect it on the client page.
But I want to fetch the data directly in the client page.
I tried it with useEffect but it only returned the database data on a hot reload but not on the initial page load.
I hope its possible to understand my question.

Code of my server page to fetch the data.

```
import prisma from "src/libs/prisma";
import RinderListPage from "./page-client";

const Page = async () => {
    let rinder: any = await prisma.rinder.findMany();

    return <RinderListPage rinder={rinder}></RinderListPage>;
};

export default Page;
```

I have also an API Endpoint with this data since its not possible to use prisma on a client page.

I tried to fetch the data trought  useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/rinder/list')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your API response to appear before the page loads then in that case you need to have a server component. In the case of the client component, the only way you can do this is with the useEffect hook, while the API is loading you can show a loading screen.

Another way if you want to fetch data before the page loads, you have to firt make you page as server component, create another component file where you can make use of "use client" and other part of your code. to this component you can pass the response that u get from page.tsx to child component as props which you are already did I can see.